# How do I query the contents of an error message in the Windows event log?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log, eventviewer

So I've got an application event log...let's call it "CustomApplicationLog"

I've also got an awesome application...let's call it "MyAwesomeApplication"

Assuming this application were to ever throw an error...**how can I use the XML query editor to search for an arbitrary string insite the event log message?**

Below is the query generated for me after picking most of the things I wanted.  I can't find any documentation on parsing this out myself though.

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="CustomApplicationLog">
    <Select Path="CustomApplicationLog">*[System[Provider[@Name='MyAwesomeApplication'] and (Level=2)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="CustomApplicationLog">
   <Select Path="CustomApplicationLog">*[System[Provider[@Name='MyAwesomeApplication'] and (Level=2)]] and *[EventData[Data and (Data='string i'm looking for')]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

This is assuming your custom application spits out the sting in the EventData section. It searches the entire Event Data section of the log for that string. To get a better idea, find the log you're looking for and check out the XML View.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://serverfault.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://serverfault.com/privileges/comment).